# antd react seting font size on breakpoint

Tags: reactjs, antd

how can I set the font size depending on the breakpoint in antd react?

```
<Text type={"secondary"} style={{fontSize: '36px'}}>Message to {userName}</Text>
```

Comment: Should not this question be tagged with [tag:css]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With antd you would use the useBreakpoint hook which returns the current breakpoints reached. Then just conditionally choose the fontsize depending on what breakpoints are returned from useBreakpoint.

```
const Component = () => {
  const {lg} = useBreakpoint(); // lg is one of the elements returned if screenwidth exceeds 991
  const myFontSize = lg ? '36px' : '24px';
  return (
    <Text type={"secondary"} style={{fontSize: myFontSize}}>Message to {userName}</Text>
  )
}
```

This code would at >=992 screenwidth have fontsize 36 and for <992 it would use 24. If you want custom breakpoints or behavior you can always use normal css with media and classes to achive the same.

docs for breakpoints
https://ant.design/components/layout/

Comment: how do you import the useBreakpoint from ant design?

Comment: https://ant.design/components/grid#components-grid-demo-usebreakpoint